# How do I link a dockerized python script to a mysql docker container to load data on the same host?

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-build

I have two docker containers running in an Ubuntu 16.04 machine, one docker container has a `mysql` sever running, the other container holds a dockerized `python` script set to run a cron job every minute that loads data into `mysql`. How can I connect the two to load data through the python script into the mysql container? I have an error showing up:
Here are my relevant commands:

**MYSQL container runs without issue:**

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=yourPassword --name icarus -d mysql_docker_image

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                               NAMES
927e50ca0c7d        mysql_docker_image                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour          0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   icarus
```

**Second container holds cron and python script:**

```
 #build the container without issue    
    sudo docker run -t -i -d docker-cron

    #exec into it to check logs
    sudo docker exec -i -t container_id /bin/bash

    #check logs
    root@b149b5e7306d:/# cat /var/log/cron.log
```

**Error:**

have the following error showing up, which I believe has to do with wrong host address:

```
Caught this error: OperationalError('(pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'localhost\' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)")',)
```

**Python Script:**

```
from traffic.data import opensky
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
#from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database
import sqlalchemy
import gc


#connection and host information
host = 'localhost'
db='icarus'
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:password@'+ host+ ':3306/'+ db) #create engine connection
version= sys.version_info[0]

#functions to upload data
def upload(df,table_name):
    df.to_sql(table_name,con=engine,index=False,if_exists='append')
    engine.dispose()
    print('SUCCESSFULLY LOADED DATA INTO STAGING...')

#pull data drom api
sv = opensky.api_states()
final_df = sv.data
#quick column clean up 
print(final_df.head())
final_df=final_df.rename(columns = {'timestamp':'time_stamp'})


#insert data to staging
try:
    upload(final_df, 'flights_stg')
except Exception as error:
        print('Caught this error: ' + repr(error))
del(final_df)
gc.collect()
```

I'm assuming the error is the use of 'localhost' as my address? How would i go about resolving something like this?

**More information:**

**MYSQL Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mysql
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

**Python Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

#apt-get install -y build-essential -y  python python-dev python-pip python-virtualenv libmysqlclient-dev curl&& \

RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y build-essential -y git -y  python3.6 python3-pip libproj-dev proj-data proj-bin libgeos++-dev libmysqlclient-dev python-mysqldb curl&& \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip3 install git+https://github.com/xoolive/traffic

COPY . .

# Install cron
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install cron

# Add crontab file in the cron directory
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/simple-cron

# Add shell script and grant execution rights
ADD script.sh /script.sh
RUN chmod +x /script.sh

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/simple-cron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Run the command on container startup
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

Comment: In the Docker documentation, I recommend reading [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), even if you're not using Compose, and then [Use bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/).  You need to create a ("user-defined bridge") network and then launch both containers attached to that `--net`, and they will be able to reach other using their `--name` as DNS names.  `localhost` in Docker is almost always "this container".

Answer (score 1):

Can you share your dockerfile or compose file from MySQL container. Yes, the problem related to using localhost as host. You must use a docker service name as host. So in docker service name works as DNS. For example if your docker-compose looks like:

```
services:
mydb:
 image: mysql:5.7
 command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
 restart: always
 environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:root
   MYSQL_USER: root
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
   MYSQL_DATABASE: root
```

You must use `mydb` instead of localhost

Comment: Hey Anar. I added my dockerfiles to the question above so you can see what I am doing. In case my repo is here: https://github.com/datafaust/docker_mysql_icarus.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a user defined network bridge was the way to go here as recommended. Solved issue by:

```
docker network create my-net

docker create --name mysql \
  --network my-net \
  --publish 3306:3306 \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
  mysql:latest


docker create --name docker-cron \
  --network my-net \
  docker-cron:latest
```

docker start each of them and using the --name as the host was perfect.